Identity involving $\sinh(l\cdot\nabla_v)$
Observe that we have the identity
$$\nabla_v(v^\alpha g)=v^\alpha\nabla g+\nabla_v(v^\alpha)g.$$
Do we have something similar for the operator $\sinh(l\cdot\nabla_v)$? That is, does $$\sinh(l\cdot\nabla_v)(v^\alpha g)=v^\alpha \sinh(l\cdot\nabla_v)g+\sinh(l\cdot\nabla_v)(v^\alpha)g,$$ or variant? where $\alpha$ is a multi-index.
Attempt at proof:
On the Fourier side, we have
$$\int_v e^{-i\eta\cdot v}\sinh(l\cdot\nabla_v)(v^\alpha g(v))\,dv=\sin(l\cdot\eta)D_\eta^\alpha\widehat g(\eta).$$ But then $$D_\eta^\alpha(\sin(l\cdot \eta)\widehat g(\eta))=\sin(l\cdot \eta)D^\alpha_\eta\widehat g(\eta)+\sum_{\beta< \alpha}\begin{pmatrix}\alpha\\\beta\end{pmatrix}D^{\alpha-\beta}_\eta(\sin(l\cdot\eta))D_\eta^\beta\widehat g(\eta)$$ which is not.

why do dont you treat the sinh as 2 exponentials, giving you 2 shift operators?

Is $l$ a function of $v$ ?

As @user619894 suggested,
$$\sinh(\boldsymbol l\cdot\boldsymbol\nabla_{\boldsymbol v})=\frac{1}{2}(e^{\boldsymbol l\cdot\boldsymbol\nabla_{\boldsymbol v}}-e^{-\boldsymbol l\cdot\boldsymbol\nabla_{\boldsymbol v}})$$
Therefore,
\begin{align}
\sinh(\boldsymbol l\cdot\boldsymbol\nabla_{\boldsymbol v})(v^\alpha g)&=\frac{1}{2}(e^{\boldsymbol l\cdot\boldsymbol\nabla_{\boldsymbol v}}(v^\alpha g)-e^{-\boldsymbol l\cdot\boldsymbol\nabla_{\boldsymbol v}}(v^\alpha g))\\
&=\frac{1}{2}[(v+l)^\alpha g(\boldsymbol v+\boldsymbol l)-(v-l)^\alpha g(\boldsymbol v-\boldsymbol l)]
\end{align}
where I used the exponential shift operator property $e^{\boldsymbol a\cdot\boldsymbol\nabla_{\boldsymbol x}}f(\boldsymbol x)=f(\boldsymbol x+\boldsymbol a)$, and where I made use of the product rule for this shift operator derived in this question of mine.

I don't understand. The shift operator property you suggest would imply $e^{l\cdot\nabla_v}(v^\alpha g)=(v+l)^\alpha g(v+l)$, no?

I made an edit - $\alpha$ is a multi-index

@schrodingerscat what do you mean by multi-index exactly?

Please see the "Multi-index notation" wiki page

So $v^\alpha=v_1^{\alpha_1}\cdots v_n^{\alpha_n}$? If so your first comment is correct
